# How do I use updatePanel in asp.net without refreshing all page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I want to design a website which contains sub-categories of a product in asp.net(c#).
When I clicked a sub-category, then an image of product must be shown and the main page shouldn't be refreshed. How can I succeed it?

Comment: AJAX! http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/controls/updatepanel-control/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Read these tutorials [Asp.net Update Panel](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers) and [Introduction to the UpdatePanel Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx)

Simple and understandable

Answer (score 4):

Please refer below Ajax overview:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454.aspx