# JavaScript code for fetching list of items into a GridView

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview, pagemethods

I have a ASP.NET Web Application. On `Page_Load` a grid view with items is created. I also have a `<asp:Textbox>` and a search button. I am using `PageMethods` to get rid of the postback. 
The idea is that when the button is clicked it will call the javascript function and then it will call the `WebMethod`. The `WebMethod` returns a list of items based on the searched criteria.

How can I fetch these items and populate the GridView with them?

In other words it is something like a partial update - on button click it is supposed to update only the GridView.

Here is the code for the WebMethod:

```
[WebMethod]
    public static List<Item> SearchResults(string text)
    {
        ItemFunctions item_functions = new ItemFunctions();
        List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
        items = item_functions.searchResults(text);
        return items;
    }
```

And here is the GridView, the button and the textbox:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />
<asp:TextBox ID="search_textbox" runat="server" />
        <input type="button" id="Button1" value="Search" onclick="SearchResults();" />
        <div id="searchResults_GridView" >
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AllowPaging="true" GridLines="Both" runat="server" AllowSorting="True"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            Width="740px"
            CausesValidation="False">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="item_name" HeaderText="item_name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="item_description" HeaderText="item_description" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="item_quantity" HeaderText="item_quantity" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="category_name" HeaderText="category_name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="type_name" HeaderText="type_name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="item_available" HeaderText="item_available" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="item_serial_number" HeaderText="item_serial_number" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="item_permission_status" HeaderText="item_permission_status" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="item_location" HeaderText="item_location" />
                <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="true" SelectText="View" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        </div>
```

This is the SearchResults functions that is called on button click:

```
<script>
    function SearchResults() {
        PageMethods.SearchResults(OnSucceeded, OnFailed);
    }

    function OnSucceeded(result, userContext, methodName) {
    }

    function OnFailed(error, userContext, methodName) {
        alert("An error occured :(");
    }
</script>
```

My javascript skills are very bad and I am still learning, otherwise in theory I think that the rest of the code should work.

Comment: Keeping it into the .NET WebForms style, I would suggest you look into updatepanel control. Not exactly what you're looking for, but still a "partial update". Doing it the way you want to do it is a bit "hacking" the webforms way and may cause trouble upon refresh or so...

Comment: yes, the update panel seems do the job this time. thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in javascript, but at this point it would require you to dump the GridView's html (because after a GridView has rendered it is only HTML) and re-create a simply HTML Table. While this may be a preferred solution you will lose all data on a full postback and will be required to re-run the javascript.

You could look into using an UpdatePanel for this functionality. See the following links for help on using UpdatePanels :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454(v=vs.100).aspx

[How do I use updatePanel in asp.net without refreshing all page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929644/how-do-i-use-updatepanel-in-asp-net-without-refreshing-all-page)

Comment: in the end, i did it with the update panel. thank you for the comment.