# How to stop page refresh on button click but my button click event should fire

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, events

My requirement is i want to stop page refresh on button click but my button click event should fire.
i have tried this .But click event is not getting fired.Please suggest!!

```
 <asp:Button DataField="GetHistory" OnClick="btn_getHistory_Click" ID="btn_getHistory" runat="server"  onclientclick="return false;" autopostback="false" xmlns:asp="#unknown"/>
```

Comment: You can use update panel, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx

Answer (score 1):

try with the input element instead of asp button but if you go with asp controls then you should use ajax jquery for your event of button or you can use update panel

[How do I use updatePanel in asp.net without refreshing all page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929644/how-do-i-use-updatepanel-in-asp-net-without-refreshing-all-page)

Comment: I need "DataField" Property to be present on my button control.But there is no such property on "Input" tag

Comment: use 'value' property for this.